# How can I make a wall surface tolerant of high-bond adhesive tape?

Tags: drywall, walls, paint, plaster, drywall-anchor

When one remove acrylic (high bond) double sided tape from wall, it often damages the wall. Surface material is peeled off, usually drywall and plaster, and sometimes paint.

When one build a new house, how do one make a wall surface strong enough against tape? Is there any newly invented but rarely known drywall material or paint for this problem? Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: This really seems to be falling into the category of "product recommendation", which is explicitly off-topic. You may consider looking at a 3M product called "command strips" for attaching things to drywall without removing the paint when you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried 3M command strips before, It doesn't work well. It only works on glass and flat ceramics tile 100%. On drywall or plaster it is only 50% for the surface is not 100% flat. And, the largest command strip is 2 kg, so it drops to 1kg. I am trying to use some strong acrylics-based wall anchor which can hold more than 10 kgs.

Comment: BTW, I use a large wall anchor with three command strips. It still tears apart paint. Strips and anchor is strong enough, but in this case paint isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answers, maybe I can provide some options to make a start. A thick plastic wall paper may have a chance to solve the problem. The thing is that when moving a double side tape wall anchor, one needs a hair dryer to heat it up. It is a risk to damage wall paper. Also some decoration board on wall also can solve the problem. Ceramic or stone tiles too can perfectly solve the problem. Just ceramic tiles are usually used at bathroom so using it at living room is wired. Stone tiles will be expansive. I wonder if there is any new chemical or enhanced plaster available? Some epoxy plaster is really strong, but it is design to fix small part of a wall and to expensive and to fast dry to paint on wall. I am focused on finding an suitable material with available price.

Comment: You may as well give yourself a check-mark for this one because it's unlikely that you're going to get an answer other than something you come up with. As noted above, this really is a shopping-recommendation question...